# Converting u and v from WGS84 to NZTM2000 - Do I need to do vector conversion?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, vector, convert, matlab

I have u and v wind component values in latitude and longitude in WGS84. I want to convert this to NZTM2000. I've converted the lat/lon in ArcView - (and will try in R) - but do I need to also do some sort of adjustment to the u and v values to account for the new coordinate system?

If so, is there a formula or perhaps a method in Matlab, ArcView, or R?

Comment: For the north component, I think you would have to calculation the grid convergence (angle between true north and grid north). For the east component...it's less than the north, but still exists. Maybe create a very short line based on the component and project it?

Comment: Colleague believes that because u and v are orthogonal, and TM is conformal (also orthogonal) that calculating the convergence would be sufficient. You may also find that the convergence isn't big enough for the rotation to be visible.

Comment: Thank you mkennedy for your response! I have not been able to find any good references (textbook, manual, or paper) about the calculation that needs to be done in order to achieve this rotation. So main question now is HOW to do this!?